# Why didn't Federal cops arrest Coulson and his team?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In season 2 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, Coulson gave the Feds the address of S.H.I.E.L.D.'s headquarters for Grant Ward's arrest. S.H.I.E.L.D. was still a terrorist organization. A speech of Christian Ward at the U.N. couldn't remove this label. And, from later events (e.g. Coulson didn't ask for help from the government, but hacked the military satellite), we can assume that that label is intact.

Why didn't the cops arrest Coulson and the team or why didn't the military simply attack the headquarters?

Answer (score 10):

During [*A Fractured House*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fractured_House), Coulson strikes a deal with Christian Ward:

> I struck a deal with the senator. He'll reverse his Anti-SHIELD proposal in exchange for his brother..

While SHIELD has officially been labeled outlaws, they have seemingly backed down from their active pursuit of Coulson and his team. This is backed up by the fact that Talbot and his men let May and the others go with no attempt to arrest them. This does not, however, mean that they're going to help them, or even permit them unfettered access to military or government satellites.

As to whether or not Coulson gave the feds the address of SHIELD headquarters, there is no definitive proof of this either way, but simple logic would state that he did not.

SHIELD insignias can be seen on the uniforms of the agents/soldiers accompanying Coulson when Ward is removed from his cell.

[image: ward is pull from his cell]

The rest of the team is shown as Ward is escorted through the base, but the location of the exchange is never specified.

All we can see is that it looks to be some sort of underground parking structure.

[image: the meeting location]

While it is *possible* that Coulson may have given them the address of SHIELD's current base, it is highly unlikely.